# pandas python to onehot label several columns with same set of values

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to create features for machine learning with Python with onehot label.  The original data has let's say element_1, element_2, element3... with values like apple, banana, kiwi...

```
     element_1     element_2     element_3
1.     apple         banana          kiwi

2.     apple         

3.     banana        kiwi            

4.     kiwi          apple
```

What I am trying to do is onehot these so new features like

```
     apple     banana     kiwi
1.     1           1          1

2.     1           0          0

3.     0           1          1

4.     1           0          1
```

Thank you.

Methods had tried would create more columns than needed like element1_apple, element1_banana,...,element2_apple...

Y = TrainDF.loc[:,['ele_1','ele_2','ele_3','ele_4']]
Y1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=Y.columns, data=le2.fit_transform(Y.values.flatten()).reshape(Y.shape))

## Y2 = onehot1.fit_transform(Y1)

Thanks for commenting.  The goal of this project is to predict how to get certain characteristic with a mix of elements and its individual amount (%) (min 1 and max 4 elements).  There are four columns for element inputs and about 50 types of elements.  Let's say if an RGB value (100,50,150) is wanted, A element 5% + D element 8% are the input needed.  Label encoding and onehot encoding don't have good outcome yet.  I  am working on organizing the data so the output for training can look like below.

```
     apple     banana     kiwi
1.     1           2          1

2.     3           0          0

3.     0           1          5

4.     1           0          1
```

Comment: Please show us the *code* for your latest attempt(s).

Comment: This isn't exactly one-hot encoding. One-hot encoding takes categorical information, you're essentially just saying TRUE FALSE TRUE, which is fine, but if you treat it as one-hot instead of boolean information you may get unexpected results depending on the model you're trying to fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
pd.get_dummies(df.stack(), prefix=None, prefix_sep=None).sum(level=0)
```

Output:

```
    apple  banana  kiwi
1.      1       1     1
2.      1       0     0
3.      0       1     1
4.      1       0     1
```